# How to find gaps in list?

Tags: software-recommendation, find, filename, scripts

So, I have allot of files (167k) and now they are now in proper order, thanks to Serg's script in here - https://askubuntu.com/a/686829/462277 .

And now I need to find gaps between filenames, the diference should be 15 and more

```
Aaaa.bb - 000002 tag tag_tag 9tag  
Aaaa.bb - 000125 tag tag_tag 9tag  
Aaaa.bb - 000130 tag tag_tag 9tag
```

They all start the same and have different endings.
Everything is in external HDD.

Comment: So you want to know if there is a difference between numbers in file names ? For example there's file with number 000125 and the next closest one is 000135. Something like that ? Or you want to have a list of the missing numbers ? List i think would be easiest to implement

Comment: We need more information, as Serg mentioned. What should happen if the gap is < 15?

Comment: List of missing numbers would be best. If its less than 15 we can ignore, but if 15 and more we need to compile a list of those files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
find . -maxdepth 1  -type f -regextype posix-awk -iregex ".*[:digit:]"| sort | awk '{  if ( ($3 - previous) > 15 ) print previous"**"$3}{ previous=$3 }'
```

The code above uses `find` command which matches all of the files in the current directory that contain digits in it, sorts them, and passes on to `awk`. `awk` goes through the list, stores each number from field 3 into variable `previous` and on the next item compares `previous` with current number

Comment: Glad to help :)

Answer (score 1):

a version in python (python3 to be precise).

save the program below under the name `diff_filename.py` (make it exectuable) and use it in the following way:

```
$ ./diff_filename.py the/directory/containing/the/files
```

the program assumes that the numbers you want to compare are always in the same position of the filename (indices 10:16).

as it is now it's pretty verbose and prints out correct filenames including the difference. as soon as it hits a filename that does not respect the minimal difference it prints that out  and stops.

here's the source code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

'''
usage: ./diff_filename.py the/directory/containing/the/files
'''

import os
import  sys

MIN_DIFF = 15

the_dir = sys.argv[1]
sorted_files = sorted(os.listdir(the_dir))

last_number = None
last_file = None
for current_file in sorted_files:
    current_number = int(current_file[10:16])
    if last_number is None:
        last_number = current_number
        last_file = current_file
        continue
    diff = current_number - last_number
    if diff < MIN_DIFF:
        print('fail! "{}" and "{}" do not respect MIN_DIFF={}'.format(
            last_file, current_file, MIN_DIFF))
        break
    else:
        print('ok! "{}" and "{}" diff={}'.format(last_file, current_file, diff))

    last_number = current_number
    last_file = current_file
```

Comment: The only thing i dont know right now is this line:   $ ./diff_filename.py the/directory/containing/the/files .   Where should i put it?

Comment: I will wait for your updates, I really want to test your way and learn using python in the future.

Comment: you can put it anywhere you like and treat it like any executable.